# JQuery: How to write if attr(left) is equal to 0px?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I need to check if an elements left positioning is equal to 0px but am unsure how to go about it.

So far I have:

```
if($('#slide-panel').attr(left) == '0px'){

//do something

};
```

But I am not sure of how to make the syntax work.

Any advice would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [.position](http://api.jquery.com/position/) method:

```
if($('#slide-panel').position().left == 0){

    //do something

};
```

The position is relative to the offset parent, if you want to relative to the document, then use `.offset()` method.

Answer (score 1):

use [`.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function like this - Get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the document.

```
var p = $("#slide-panel'"); 
var offset = p.offset(); 
if(offset.left ==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try any from below:**

```
if($('#slide-panel').attr("style") == 'left:0px'){
    //do something
};
```

**OR:**

```
if($('#slide-panel').css("left") == '0px'){
    //do something
};
```

**OR:**

```
if($('#slide-panel').position().left == 0){
    //do something
};
```

Comment: The first one would only work if the attribute had the style attribute with only the value of left set to 0px, if there were any others, or it did not have a left attribute and the op was just trying to calculate the value, this would not work. The last solution is the best.